# Odoo 16 : How to add field (attributes) from the loaded model (stock.lot) to POS Orderline depends on product SN?

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

Briefly I will show what I'm seeking for, I customized stock.lot model added attributes filed on it depends on product unique serial number. Then I loaded the stock.lot model to POS now I need to display attributes field in every orderline depends on product serial number. How can I manage it ?

to add field (attributes) from the loaded model (stock.lot) to POS Orderline depends on product SN

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, there are two aspects of what you require. One is to show it in the model at the orders page. The other one is showing in POS screen. For the first one is to inherit `pos.order.line` and add a related field depending on the product. For the second one, you need to inherit JS and XML elements of POS to be able to display on the POS screen. You can find them under `src` in `pos_sale` module. Depending on the location you want to display on the screen, inherit the related JS and XML elements and add the field you want to display.

Comment: First thanks for your interest, yes I mean the second aspect and I know the steps what should I do. Exactly like what you said but I don't know how to do it correctly. How can I get One2many field values from custom module with product serial number to show in pos orderline